# LateInitializationError from another page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i am using flutter for coding at the moment
so I created a global variable named DrugList

```
                Late List List of Medicines;
```

then I took data from firebase to fill in the Medicines List

```
      StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
             stream: RSGM.doc(widget.namarsgm).snapshots(),
             builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                       snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

           listMedicine = [
                for (int i = 0; i <= data['Medicine'].length - 1; i++)
                  {
                   'Name': data['Medicine'][i]['Name'],                    
                   }
                ];
                .... 
                ....
```

then i want to use list1 in code in another page

```
                         CustomSearchableDropDown(
                         items: listMedicine,
                         labels: 'medicine',
                          ...
                          ...
                          ...
                          )
```

But there it is written
LateInitializationError: Field 'listMedicine' has not been initialized.

does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling CustomSearchableDropDown() Widget inside if (snapshot.hasData) {}? When CustomSearchableDropDown() Widget is called outside of (snapshot.hasData), the listMedicine will not be initialized.

This will cause error

```dart
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: RSGM.doc(widget.namarsgm).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      listMedicine = [
      for (int i = 0; i <= data['Medicine'].length - 1; i++)
        {
          'Name': data['Medicine'][i]['Name'],                    
          }
      ];
    }
    return CustomSearchableDropDown();
  }
)
```

Change it something like this

```dart
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: RSGM.doc(widget.namarsgm).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      listMedicine = [
      for (int i = 0; i <= data['Medicine'].length - 1; i++)
        {
          'Name': data['Medicine'][i]['Name'],                    
          }
      ];
      return CustomSearchableDropDown();
    } else {
      return Text('Loading');
    }
  }
)
```